# Cannot fetch object CoreData correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am practicing using CoreData to store data and fetch data.
But I met some issues which confused me for several hours.
I stored a group of objects from index 0 - 107, totally are 108. It works perfectly.

**NSLog of some data stored:**

```
2015-03-04 16:39:29.825 Colo[32365:1884749] <NSManagedObject: 0x7f83d06a7240> (entity: Color; id: 0xd000000000300000 <x-coredata://3DC5B29F-DA7C-4D7C-9D59-738A28A957C1/Color/p12> ; data: {
  colorArray = nil;
  fifthColor = "#5A3431";
  firstColor = "#F2EDDA";
  fourthColor = "#A65F4B";
  hexString = nil;
  index = 106;
  secondColor = "#BEAC94";
  star = 12;
  thirdColor = "#DA896E";
  title = "wm102\n        \n        ";
})
2015-03-04 16:39:29.826 Colo[32365:1884749] 107
2015-03-04 16:39:29.826 Colo[32365:1884749] <NSManagedObject: 0x7f83d06a7330> (entity: Color; id: 0xd000000000980000 <x-coredata://3DC5B29F-DA7C-4D7C-9D59-738A28A957C1/Color/p38> ; data: {
  colorArray = nil;
  fifthColor = "#242613";
  firstColor = "#100C17";
  fourthColor = "#FFE8B4";
  hexString = nil;
  index = 107;
  secondColor = "#604325";
  star = 12;
  thirdColor = "#D0A17D";
  title = "Create Now 2014 \U4f1a\U5834\n        \n        ";
})
```

But when I try to fetch these objects that I had stored to CoreData.

```
- (void)fetchDataFromCoreData
{
  AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Color"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:entityDescription];

  NSError *error;

  NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

  if (!objects){
    NSLog(@"There was an error.");
  }

  for (NSManagedObject *oneObject in objects){
    NSString *title       = [oneObject valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *star        = [oneObject valueForKey:@"star"];
    NSString *index       = [oneObject valueForKey:@"index"];
    NSString *firstColor  = [oneObject valueForKey:@"firstColor"];
    NSString *secondColor = [oneObject valueForKey:@"secondColor"];
    NSString *thirdColor  = [oneObject valueForKey:@"thirdColor"];
    NSString *fourthColor = [oneObject valueForKey:@"fourthColor"];
    NSString *fifthColor  = [oneObject valueForKey:@"fifthColor"];
    int i = [index intValue];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    ColorCell *cell = (ColorCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    UIColor *first  = [Parser translateStringToColor:firstColor];
    UIColor *second = [Parser translateStringToColor:secondColor];
    UIColor *third  = [Parser translateStringToColor:thirdColor];
    UIColor *fourth = [Parser translateStringToColor:fourthColor];
    UIColor *fifth  = [Parser translateStringToColor:fifthColor];

    cell.firstColor.backgroundColor  = first;
    cell.secondColor.backgroundColor = second;
    cell.thirdColor.backgroundColor  = third;
    cell.fourthColor.backgroundColor = fourth;
    cell.fifthColor.backgroundColor  = fifth;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `cell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` reused in a strange way, some cell are blank, and only one cell appear. I made two breakpoints at

```
     int i = [index intValue];
     NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
```

And I noted that the index is break, which 82 should be the next one of 81.

Any idea would very welcomed.

[image]
[image]

This is my first CoreData practise. Please help me to become better.

**EDIT**: Subclass `NSManagedObject`:
.h:

```
@interface ColorManagerObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) UIColor *firstColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *secondColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *thirdColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *fourthColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *fifthColor;

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)setFirstColor:(UIColor *)firstColor
{
  [self setValue:firstColor forKey:@"firstColor"];
}

- (UIColor *)firstColor
{
  NSString *string = [self valueForKey:@"firstColor"];
  return [Parser translateStringToColor:string];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your fetchRequest has no sortDescriptors, so the objects are not returned in a particular order.
2. That is not how tableViews work.

Let's fix the first problem first, simply add a NSSortDescriptor.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSSortDescriptor *indexSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[indexSortDescriptor];
```

The second problem is more complicated to explain. The TableView uses the dataSource pattern. It asks your dataSource for objects, you don't send objects to the tableView. You should store the result of the fetch in an NSArray, and use that array as your dataSource. Then implement the three basic UITableViewDataSource methods.

e.g.:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *objects;

- (void)fetchDataFromCoreData {
    // ...
    self.objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // reload tableView so it contains all the new objects
    // ...
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.objects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    NSManagedObject *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"title"];
    return cell;
}
```

---

And once that works you might want to read about [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/), which is basically made for UITableViews that are backed by Core Data. It offers a nice delegate that will insert and remove cells when objects are inserted or removed from CoreData.

You might also want to check out NSManagedObject subclasses, so you don't have to use `[object valueForKey:@"title"]` and can use `object.title` instead.

Comment: THANKS ! You are exactly right! And that 's how I used to install a tableView. Awesome  `NSFetchedResultsController` class you  referred to. By the way, I subclassed `NSManagedObject`, but seems I had met some problem. I edit my post include it.